# Bootstrap 3 - Navigation buttons overlapping text issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the fiddle to see issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/nn6ydqcw/1/

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation ">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="height:150px;background-color:#FFFFFF">
            <div class="col-md-3" ><a href="index"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/200px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png"></a></div>
            <div class="col-md-9" ><h1>Tag line will come here and it will be managed dynamically</h1></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
                    <li><a href="home">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I am using Bootstrap 3 in above code and it works fine on desktop / laptop etc. But when I see it in mobile or resized browser to see in smaller screen, it is displaying in following sequence. So problem is that in smaller screen when I click on toggle icon then navigation buttons overlaps tag line.

1. Logo
2. Navigation Toggle Icon
3. Text based Tag line

I want to do so they display in following sequence. So even when I see them in smaller screen, navigation buttons should not overlap tag line.

1. Logo
2. Text based Tag line
3. Toggle Navigation Toggle Icon

Please let me know how can I get required result.

Comment: Simply update your html with the code i have provided, tested & works perfectly.

Comment: Try using the `col-xs-*` classes instead of the `col-md-*` classes, although when the width gets small enough, eventually the text will not fit and will overlap the navbar.

Comment: @Ahir, was a bit tuff to render as per your need, but finally its done. Good luck & hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as follows:

**CSS:**

```
     @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     body {
     background-color: orange; //FOR TESTING PURPOSE
     }

     #tagstyle {
      position: relative;
      left: 220px;
      top: -200px;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 60%;      
      }
}
```

**HTML:** [Add an id as shown below]

```
<h1 id="tagstyle">Tag line will come here and it will be managed dynamically</h1>
```

**Desktop View:**
[image]

**Mobile View:**
 [image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But tag line should be at right side of the logo when see in desktop / laptop large screens. And in mobile / smaller screen, it is still have same issue. Here is updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nn6ydqcw/3/

Comment: Ty for your efforts...It's working as expected in smaller screens as we can see in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nn6ydqcw/6/ ... But in desktop / large screen logo is not overlapped on grey strip as you can see in initial fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nn6ydqcw/1/

Comment: I'm not clear with what is expected? PLease give detailed explanation for for small & medium devices?

Comment: For large screen (desktop / laptop), tagline should be displayed at right side of logo. Logo should be overlapped to grey color navigation menu (like in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nn6ydqcw/1/). This can be done without any issue. But for small screen (mobile), tagline should be moved under logo or can be at right side of logo so tagline should not be overlapped when toggle icon in grey navigation menu clicked. I hope this will help you to understand issue properly. If not then please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, please check the updated code as per your requirement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107142/discussion-between-dev-and-k-ahir).

Comment: Sorry for delay in reply. I tried your suggested code but still not getting proper output. I think we are not on the same page. Ok about chat so I will send you message there from now.

Answer (score -1):

Check the style="height:150px;background-color:#FFFFFF" you're having conflict in the height:150px; And I think you need to use the push and pull in bootstrap.